# Change Data with Switch on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i am quite new to iOS and Swift and want to solve a Problem with UITableViewCell

I have a ControllerClass with a  UITableView that has a Custom UITableViewCell called ArtistCell as following

```
public class ArtistCell: UITableViewCell {

var value : Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var artistSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var artistTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func changedBoolValue(sender: UISwitch) {
    self.value = sender.on
}

public func configure(text: String, enabledArtist: Bool) -> Bool{
    self.artistSwitch.on = enabledArtist
    self.value = enabledArtist
    self.artistTextField.text = text

    return self.value

}
```

In this class as you can see, there is a textfield and a switch. If this switch is clicked the value of this list item in my ViewController should be changed

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


...

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var profile : UserProfile = UserProfile()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10
  ...  
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.profile.artists.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //get my own cell  
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ArtistCell

    //initialize cell and get back the actual Value of the switch and set it to my object???
    let boolValue : Bool = cell.configure(     self.profile.artists[indexPath.row].name, enabledArtist: self.profile.artists[indexPath.row].display.boolValue )

    //this following value should be set in my object
    profile.artists[indexPath.row].display = boolValue

    return cell

}
}
```

now i want to know how i should set the bool value of my switch to my object?

Comment: have you looked into delegation? You may want to create a delegate for your cell, which updates your view controller when the switch is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have default value from switch when your cell is created. To set new value for `dataModel` in `ViewController` when your switch state changed you can use  delegate mechanism.

Create protocol for your action:

```
protocol SwitchChangedDelegate {
    func changeStateTo(isOn: Bool, row: Int)
}
```

Make your `ProfileViewController` class confirm this protocol:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SwitchChangedDelegate {
    ...
    func changeStateTo(isOn: Bool, row: Int) {
        // here update your dataModel
        profile.artists[row].display = isOn
    }
    ...
}
```

Add to your `ArtistCell` delegate object with type on protocol and row variable:

```
var delegate: SwitchChangedDelegate?
var row: Int?
```

Set delegate and row at your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`:

```
cell.delegate = self
cell.row = indexPath.row
```

Call protocol method in your `changedBoolValue` func:

```
@IBAction func changedBoolValue(sender: UISwitch) {
    ...
    self.delegate?.changeStateTo(sender.on, row: row)
}
```

Comment: thank you, didn't think of delegates but it works now. 
I think now i understand better how delegates work and where to use them :)

Answer (score 2):

Define `protocol` before `ArtistCell`:

```
protocol ArtistTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didChangeSwitchValue(value: Bool, artistName: String)
}


public class ArtistCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: ArtistTableViewCellDelegate?
    var value: Bool =  false
    @IBOutlet weak var artistSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func changedBoolValue(sender: UISwitch) {
        self.value = sender.on
        delegate?.didChangeSwitchValue(value, artistName: artistTextField.text!)
    }
}
```

And in your `ViewController`:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ArtistTableViewCellDelegate {

    //...
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //get my own cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ArtistCell

        //initialize cell and get back the actual Value of the switch and set it to my object???
        let boolValue : Bool = cell.configure(     self.profile.artists[indexPath.row].name, enabledArtist: self.profile.artists[indexPath.row].display.boolValue )

        //this following value should be set in my object
        profile.artists[indexPath.row].display = boolValue
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell

    }

    //...

    func didChangeSwitchValue(value: Bool, artistName: String) {
        //do sth with your value
    }

}
```

You can also do some refactor in `ArtistCell` to achieve:

```
func didChangeSwitchValue(value: Bool, artistID: Int)
```

or:

```
func didChangeSwitchValue(value: Bool, artist: YOUR_ARTIST_TYPE)
```

Comment: thank you so much, tested your solution and it works aswell as the solution of alex_p